# Changing value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to figure out in Google Sheets if there is a way to do this.

**FROM SHEET1**:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 10 |
| XYZ | 20 |
| ABC | 15 |
| XYZ | 25 |

**TO SHEET2**

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | =SUM(100+10+15) |
| XYZ | =SUM(100+20+25) |

1. Any time I change the value for ABC to value 0, it should add 10. So for every value in Sheet1, it should add value in sheet2 only when I make the value 0 in Sheet1
2. I have multiple ABC, XYZ in Sheets1, so I want to link each ABC in Sheet2 from Sheet1

I want to see if this is possible in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

> ABC   =SUM(100+10+15)
>
> XYZ   =SUM(100+20+25)

try:

```
=QUERY(A1:B, "select A,100+sum(B) where B>0 group by A label 100+sum(B)''")
```

[image]

Comment: i don't want 100 to be a default.  I tried doing B1 instead of 100 but, it is giving a #value error

Comment: @user9238493490 try: `=QUERY(A1:B, "select A,"&B1&"+sum(B) where B>0 group by A label "&B1&"+sum(B)''")`

Comment: this is only doing it for one sheet.  If i have the second sheet I want to match the key word (column A) from sheet 1 to sheet 2 and  take the value (column B) from sheet1 and add it to the total on sheet2 (columnB) ... How would i do this? (those values are just examples)

Comment: @user9238493490 share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: see link: [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mkLmFIikMXuLVeUvF3bXccTCObDrqANlUPLN3Jwo1M4/edit#gid=1546114759
See Sheet2 for explanation

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a SUM per value but also consider the 0s as 10s?

Try this:

```
={UNIQUE(Sheet1!A:A),BYROW(UNIQUE (Sheet1!A:A),LAMBDA(each,100+SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,each,Sheet1!B:B)+10*COUNTIFS(Sheet1!B:B,0,Sheet1!A:A,each)))}
```

Comment: yes, after I make the value 0 (manually), I want to change that value in sheet2 to (x+10).  I want to do this for the selected name for each row.